# Send left mouse to click handler from code?

Tags: c#, wpf, mouseevent

I have the following mouseclick event:

```
public static void ni_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    // Handle mouse button clicks.
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

This is usually triggered by clicking the icon in the systray with a left click,

I would like to also call this same event from another event, I have tried something like:

```
myproject.ProcessIcon.ni_MouseClick(sender, mousebutton.left);
```

but obviously I'm not sure how to send the left button object correctly (if possible).

Comment: `ni_MouseClick(sender, new MouseEventArgs(MouseButtons.Left, 0, 0, 0, 0);` ??

Comment: What data type is myproject?

Comment: @Lucifer works a treat just needed an additional )); at the end. Thanks write it up as a answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any operation which can be triggered by user interaction (click), can obviously be triggered by other code.

put any functionality which should be performed more than once in a separate method and invoke that method from different places in code:

```
public static void DoStuff()
{
}

private void ni_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    // Handle mouse button clicks.
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        DoStuff();
    }
}

myproject.ProcessIcon.DoStuff();
```

Comment: Thanks although @Lucifer suggestion works, this method is better as i can return the MouseClick back to private. Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the method within your second method. Something like:

```
public void SecondMethod(object sender, Args e){
    ni_MouseClick(sender, e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

simply change your code as below :-

```
ni_MouseClick(sender, new MouseEventArgs(MouseButtons.Left, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

But you need to think and implement as per Ash's answer he has better solution.